# Adding two header images side-by-side in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, header

I'm trying to add a second header image beside the default in a Wordpress child theme based on Arras.  Right now, only the first one, the left image, is appearing.  At the right there is nothing but blank space.  I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong--whether it's an error in my markup or a constraint of the theme itself.

Here's what it looks like right now: http://traycezpr.currentecalamo.org/

```
#header {
    height:165px;
    width:960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    background:transparent;
    border:none;
}

#header h1 {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:800px;
    height:165px;
background:url(http://traycezpr.currentecalamo.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/TZLTER.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size: 800px; 165px;
    text-indent:-10000px;
}

#header h2 {
    display:inline;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    width:160px;
    height:165px:
    text-indent:-10000px;   background:url(http://traycezpr.currentecalamo.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/TZCH7.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size:160px; 165px;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, you've got an error in your css. You've put a colon instead of a semicolon after `height:165px` on your h2. And you can't define a property like this: `background-size: 800px; 165px;`. The semicolon ends the declaration. Using developer tools (chrome) or firebug (firefox) instantly highlights these issues so you can quickly debug, give them a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user.css line 22 you've got incorrect code. It reads:

```
height:165px: text-indent:-10000px
```

Whereas it should read:

```
height:165px;
text-indent:-10000px;
```

You've also got `.logo` (which the `h` tags are nested in) set to:

```
max-width:590px
```

You should have this span the whole width so something like:

```
width:100%
```

I would also recommend using actual `divs` instead of `h` tags for your images. `h` tags are normally used for text titles/seo.

Comment: Thanks.  I fixed the errors and removed the float:right under h2, added left:800px to get the two images in line.  Will have to work on turning these into divs, but for now this was helpful.

Comment: No worries, I'd definitely look into those `h` tags though. It would be as simple as changing `<h1...></h1>` to `<div...></div>` and a small adjustment in your css style.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

1. add height:165px; to #header hs
2. on line 48 in default.css (.logo) change max-width to 100%

Comment: And... your background-size has a ; in it.. That should not be there.. ;)